# AWS Sagemaker | How to debug docker image | What the parameter we pass

Tags: docker, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

We want to upload a docker image which have our custom code for tensorflow, now we followed this standard code 
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/tensorflow_bring_your_own/tensorflow_bring_your_own.ipynb

We are able to upload docker there with our dependency but we are not able to pass the S3 location to their method, now we are not sure if the S3 location is passing to the container or not so added print which is not printing on sagemaker. Can someone please help how to debug the docker as the custom log is also not available on cloudwatch.

```
018-11-30 09:55:17 Uploading - Uploading generated training model
2018-11-30 09:55:17 Failed - Training job failed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-5fc1c1e7ed65> in <module>()
     11                       hyperparameters=hyperparameters)
     12 
---> 13 estimator.fit(data_location)
     14 
     15 # predictor = estimator.deploy(1, instance_type)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in fit(self, inputs, wait, logs, job_name)
    232         self.latest_training_job = _TrainingJob.start_new(self, inputs)
    233         if wait:
--> 234             self.latest_training_job.wait(logs=logs)
    235 
    236     def _compilation_job_name(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in wait(self, logs)
    571     def wait(self, logs=True):
    572         if logs:
--> 573             self.sagemaker_session.logs_for_job(self.job_name, wait=True)
    574         else:
    575             self.sagemaker_session.wait_for_job(self.job_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in logs_for_job(self, job_name, wait, poll)
   1121 
   1122         if wait:
-> 1123             self._check_job_status(job_name, description, 'TrainingJobStatus')
   1124             if dot:
   1125                 print()

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in _check_job_status(self, job, desc, status_key_name)
    821             reason = desc.get('FailureReason', '(No reason provided)')
    822             job_type = status_key_name.replace('JobStatus', ' job')
--> 823             raise ValueError('Error for {} {}: {} Reason: {}'.format(job_type, job, status, reason))
    824 
    825     def wait_for_endpoint(self, endpoint, poll=5):

ValueError: Error for Training job tensor-2018-11-30-09-52-12-964: Failed Reason: AlgorithmError: Exception during training: Return Code: 1, CMD: ['/usr/bin/python', 'cifar10.py', '--model-dir', '/opt/ml/model', '--train-steps', '100'], Err: b'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.\n  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "cifar10.py", line 195, in <module>\n    main()\n  File "cifar10.py", line 188, in main\n    interactions_processed, user_meta_processed, item_meta_processed, item_feats_set = process_data(interaction_data, interaction_cols, users_meta, users_meta_cols, items_meta, items_meta_cols, user_meta_filterlist=user_meta_list)\n  File "cifar10.py", line 32, in process_data\n    df=pd.read_csv(interaction_data, engine=\'c\', encoding=\'latin1\', usecols=interaction_cols).astype(str)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/d
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error message, this seems to be a problem that isn't in the original example that you followed.

Diagnosing and debugging this might require a bit more details in regards to your cifar10.py file, as the stack trace provided doesn't seem to match the original cifar10.py file in the example:
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/tensorflow_bring_your_own/container/cifar10/cifar10.py

Also, I understand that iteration can be incredibly slow, so I recommend making use of local mode to speed up iterations before productionizing on SageMaker. The example notebook cited above cites this and this can be done by using 'local' as the value for train_instance_type or instance_type for training/hosting.

Does your example work with your dataset provided from a local directory(file:///)?

If it does, however doesn't work in SageMaker, that might be because your not expecting your dataset to be in the right directory. SageMaker will push your data to a specific channel as specified here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo.html#your-algorithms-training-algo-running-container-trainingdata

Please let me know if there is anything I can clarfiy.

Comment: I tried to run it on local mode but my docker is not loading on local mode, seems it does not find it valid location, have you run the same on your local mode ?

Comment: Can you please provide the Python code that is being used to invoke local mode?

Debugging something that is custom made from an individual is difficult without knowing details on the container, environment and etc. Please provide as much information as comfortably possible!